# Why does my PHP/MySQL update query not function at all?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an update query only run depending on whether the current entry is the first (`$count`). The problem is that my update query isn't doing anything, but it is definitely entering the if statement. Here is my code:

```
if ($count <= 0) {
  echo json_encode('entered if');
  $conn->query( "UPDATE tblProjects SET ProjectStatus = 2, StartDate = '$por' WHERE PROJECTNOID = '$proj'");
  exit();
 }else{
  echo json_encode('entered else');
  exit();
 }
```

As I mentioned this earlier I can type this into mysql editor with values and it will update no problem. I also know that the values for `$proj` and `$por` are correct. I am running `echo json_encode($proj);` and `echo json_encode($por);` and they return `"195""2018-07-19"` in the browser. Thus is the reason why I believe the problem is with `$conn->query( "UPDATE tblProjects SET ProjectStatus = 2, StartDate = '$por' WHERE PROJECTNOID = '$proj'");`

Nothing gets logged in the error log I made. Also don't comment about prepared statements I am already aware. If I refresh the form multiple times, this creates more entries and for some reason runs the update query when it shouldn't.

**EDIT: This seems to work if I use:**

```
  if ($count <= 0) {
   echo json_encode('entered if');
   $qr = "UPDATE tblProjects SET ProjectStatus = 2, StartDate = '$por' WHERE PROJECTNOID = '$proj'";
   $conn->query($qr);
   echo json_encode($qr);
   exit();
  }else{
   echo json_encode('entered else');
   exit();
  }
```

But I still don't understand why this happens. Aren't these two ways the same thing?

**EDIT 2: Full Script with the jQuery that posts to this script**

Full Script (PHP):

```
<?php
  require "../../inc/dbinfo.inc";

  ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("log_errors", 1);
  ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
  error_log( "#################################################     UP-PROJECT-STATUS.PHP    #################################################" );

  $proj = $_POST['projectnum'];
  $por = $_POST['por'];

  //Check count of customer pos
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numpo FROM tblCustomerPOs WHERE ProjectNum = '$proj'"); //On the first customer po for the project
  $res = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
  $count = $res->numpo;
  $count = intval($count);


  if ($count <= 0) {
   echo json_encode('entered if');
   $conn->query( "UPDATE tblProjects SET ProjectStatus = 2, StartDate = '$por' WHERE PROJECTNOID = '$proj'");
   echo json_encode($qr);
   exit();
  }else{
   echo json_encode('entered else');
   exit();
  }
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(){
            var projectnum = $('#projectnum').val();
            var por = $('#porval').val();
            var data_String;
             data_String = 'projectnum='+projectnum+'&por='+por;
             if (por) {
               $.post('fetch/up-project-status.php',data_String,function(data){
                 var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               });
             }
            });
```

Comment: Try echoing your query and running it directly into the database. See if it works or if it throws an error.

Comment: Are you using `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: @RiggsFolly mysqli

Comment: If this is mysqli, add `or die($conn->error)` to the end of the `$conn->query` line to see if it's reporting an error.

Comment: About your: *"If I refresh the form multiple times, this creates more entries and for some reason runs the update query when it shouldn't."* : ok, so is there not a unique constraint on any of those columns? Are you wanting to not have the same record(s) added?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly see the edit I just made, it seems to work with an edit I just made but it doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: @aynber I just echoed the statement $qr and it came back as how I wanted it and also fixed my problem but I still don't know how it did.

Comment: seeing the edit and the only thing I see different is the `exit();` being omitted; you running this from JS somewhere? or any web service? exit stops execution.

Comment: Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes this is a server side script that I'm using for long polling. I send 2 variables to this page using jquery. Im about to test it with `exit()` and see if i get the same result.

Comment: Hm... yeah seems a bit odd, and the other query not having an variable used, really odd.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ok, I just tested and it also works with `exit()`. Could this just be a glitch? My error log saw no action the whole time. The other query just uses a variable to see how many columns there currently are with the number given.

Comment: @Jordan Hm.... it's hard to say if it's a glitch. Tell you the truth, I'm baffled.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'll add the whole script as well with the jQuery if someone wants to do some more investigating